# Biblioteca Os/ python

Tags: python

Esse programa tem como objetivo mostrar determinado tipo de arquivo que tem em uma pasta. Mas está dando o seguinte:

```
erro: WindowsError: [Error 2] O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado: 'pythonteste'.
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar a resolver esse problema ?

---

```
import os
import glob


current_directory= os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
os.chdir('pythonteste')
files= glob.glob('*.txt')
for file in files:
    print(file)
```

Comment: Verifique se o diretório `pythonteste` existe na pasta onde você está rodando o projeto, ou passe o caminha absoluto até a pasta que tem os arquivos que você deseja. Obs: nesse trecho de código o `current_directory` não está sendo necessário.

Comment: A parta não estava no diretório do projeto, agora funcionou ! Muito Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Esse erro está acontecendo porque o diretório `pythontest` não existe.

Você poderá criá-lo caso não exista pela própria aplicação:

```
if not os.path.exists(directory):
    os.makedirs(directory)
```

Comment: A pasta pythonteste não estava no diretório que o projeto era executado e por isso não estava funcionando, Obrigado pela ajuda !

Answer (score -1):

Só outra forma de condição ;)

```
If( os.path.exists(directory) == False ): 
   os.makedirs(directory)
```